# laravel model best practice

Tags: postgresql, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, modeling

Hi I'm using laravel in my current project. I thought its recommended to create a model for each database table to get the best out of eloquent's Relationships

somewhere in my Database I have this mapping table to map records from table A to table B (many to many)

should I create a model for my mapping table ? what is the best practice in such cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is best answered from an architetural point of view:

Models are made to represent entities. Mapping Tables do not store entities but information about relationships between entitites (many-to-many). Therefore, creating models for mapping tables does not make much sense.

Laravel offers a concepts called pivot-table for this kind of usecase, which is very well documented in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns).